# Не выводится список React Native

Tags: json, reactjs

Не работает вывод в List View

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

const data = require('./assets/upr/categories.json');

class AppBB extends Component {
    renderList (data) {
        data.map((upr) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{upr.uprtitle}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <ListView
                ref="listView"
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderList}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Пишет

> null is not an object (evaluting this.state.dataSource)

Comment: метод `renderList` не возвращает данные у вас. Отсутствует `return` перед `data.map(...)`

Comment: Так же `styles`, которые используется в `renderList` будут `undefined` и упадут при обращении к свойству.

Comment: И кстати говоря у вас отсутствует `this.state` оно null и не обработано в конструкторе класса `AppBB`